# Where does security information in WI-FI such as the PTK and GTK is being stored on my computer? Can I display it?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, security, network-adapter

I'm currently trying to explore the 802.11i protocol and I wondered where does the PTK and GTK are stored on my computer. Is it actually on my NIC or it is stored somewhere else? Can I access it? If yes then is there a shell command to display this information?

I couldn't find those answers anywhere and I could really use some help. Thanks!

Comment: Without looking further into it, most likely in RAM. Definitely not on your network card

Comment: Well I'm sorry but I need more than a guess.

Comment: It seems like you got the idea that with the temporal keys you will be able to decode wireless traffic. If you really want to take this route instead of easier methods with existing software, you may consider reading some information about 802.11 security published by the IEEE: https://paginas.fe.up.pt/~jaime/0506/SSR/802.11i-2004.pdf  https://www.ieee802.org/1/files/public/docs2004/AFjul04KimKey_Management_For_Link_Layer_Security.pdf